# Lambda: The Ultimate Imperative - who is Jensen?

Tags: ho.history-overview

One of the notes in the classical paper [LAMBDA: The Ultimate Imperative](http://repository.readscheme.org/ftp/papers/ai-lab-pubs/AIM-353.pdf) says:

> {Jensensdevice}
>
> The technique of repeatedly modifying a variable passed call-by-name in order to produce side effects on another call-by-name parameter is commonly known as Jensen's device, particularly in the case where call-by-name parameters are *j* and *a[j]*. **We cannot find any reference to Jensen or who he was, and offer a reward for any information leading to the identification, arrest, and conviction of said Jensen.**

Today, after almost 40 years since the memo was published, do we know the identity of Jensen? I'm not hoping for the reward, just curious.

Comment: Did you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_Device ?

Comment: No, as you might guess from the question. I tried googling "Who is Jensen from Lambda the Ultimate" but it didn't cross my mind to just google "Jensen's device". I guess that was too simple :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Jensen's device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_Device) was developed by [Jørn Jensen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B8rn_Jensen), who worked on one of the earliest ALGOL 60 compilers (this answer is based on [comment by Kristoffer Arnsfelt Hansen](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16158/lambda-the-ultimate-imperative-who-is-jensen#comment41960_16158)).